# How to force reload if back button is pressed in jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to force a page reload of my main page if the user clicks on the back button of my detail page. The strange thing is, that the following event is exactly fired as expected, but now every pages is reloaded after the back button is pressed.

```
 $(document).off("pagehide").on("pagehide", "div[id=main-page]", function(event, ui) {
  var nextPage = ui.nextPage.attr('id');
  if (nextPage === "detail-page") {
     $(event.target).remove();
  }
 });
```

BTW: the following code is included in my main page

Regards
  Roger

Comment: As in the main page is part of every page? Then behavior is as expected.

Comment: No, there is only one page with id=main-page and it is only included there. The problem is the  $(event.target).remove(); call. As soon as this is executed every back action forces a reload.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a single page application. When you are moving from one page to another the browser is not getting refreshed. What ever callback you set once will remain there unless you remove them specifically.

Comment: No, it is not a single page app. The callbacks are ok. Debugged it and the events are firing as expected.